# Звук при открытии окна

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Как сделать звук при открытии окна как у MessageBox-а с ошибкой? Я просто хочу сделать свое окошко ошибки. И еще есть ли где то встроенная картинка этого крестика как на том же MessageBoxImage.Error? Чтоб не искать его и не пихать в ресурсы.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox(v=vs.110).aspx И за чем делать своё окно, если даже звуки и крестики хотите стандартные?

Comment: @Sergey Ну и зачем мне ссылка на стандартный MessageBox? Я хотел сделать красиво: сверху отображается самая суть, например "Сервер был остановлен", а ниже в свернутом Expander-е текст исключения. Я такое просто во многих реальных приложениях видел. Хотел вот так и у себя сделать.

Answer (score 3):

Для воспроизведения стандартных системных звуков есть функция [PlaySound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms712879.aspx). В .NET функция частично обёрнута классом [System.Media.SystemSounds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.media.systemsounds.aspx). Там не все звуки, но для ваших целей хватит.

Стандартные картинки добываются с помощью функции [LoadIcon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms648072.aspx). В .NET функция обёрнута классом [SystemIcons](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.drawing.systemicons.aspx).

Всё это классы Windows.Forms. Если вы используете WPF, то вам надо будет конвертировать классы в WPF'ные. Используйте для этого класс [Imaging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.interop.imaging.aspx).

Если вам нужны продвинутые сообщения, в новых версиях системы они встроены, находятся где-то в районе функций оболочки. Обёртки для этих функций есть в библиотеке **Windows API Code Pack**. Microsoft про эту библиотеку подзабыла, но в разных формах она всё ещё жива и доступна. См. [Windows API Code Pack: Where is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24081665)